# Allowing users of laravel app to connect their own amazon aws s3, or DO spaces S3 to the app to serve files - possible?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

first post here although i've been reading for about 7 years :). Please take it easy on me if there are things that are wrong with my post.

I am working on a social network/marketplace for online education. The business problem i am dealing with is how to delegate the cost of hosting (most importantly video content) to the vendors themselves, in order to simplify the platform's relationship with them.
As an example, Patreon.com integrates with vimeo to upload videos from patreon website straight to vimeo, thus the platform is not incurring the cost of hosting creator videos.

My question is if it would be possible to do the same thing with amazon s3 or digital ocean s3. Instead of our app (laravel+vue) to have it's own hosting on amazon s3, each user of our app would be able to connect their own s3 drives, access his buckets/objects and share them on our platform. That way they can pay their own bills for hosting and we don't have to deal with "re-selling" hosting.

Has anyone gone the route of allowing their app users to enter their own S3 hosting credentials, store them in the db, and when retrieving the file, setting those credentials on the fly, as ml59 suggested, and accessing the user's s3 files.

Thanks,

Comment: depends on what type of app you are doing but you can use the aws sdk api with customer credential, that way you are just mapping the bucket with their api credential or you can use the Laravel filesystem with the customer credential (settings the disk on the fly should work fine)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: thanks ml59. I will edit the question to include your advice, wondering if anyone has tried this, and if there are any issues that may arise.